# Angular routing considerations

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have some considerations related to angular routing and I would like to know if they are all correct.

Suppose I have a route ({path:'/home', component:HomeComponent}).

To navigate to this path(/home), I can use 3 methods, for example:

1) To Enter the URL in the browser bar

2) To Insert the routerlink directive in the parent component template(in this case AppComponent)

3) To use the navigate method in the parent component class(in this case app.component.ts), this.router.navigate(['/home']).

routerLink and navigate method do the same things, they navigate to a /home route (the browser url is updated) and the component that manages this route(HomeComponent) will be displayed.

Both routerLink and navigate take as argument the same array(the same path of the route), that coincides with the path field value in the route definition {path:'/home', component:HomeComponent}.

Generally, routerLink and router-outlet must always be inserted in the parent route template, i.e. in the parent component tamplate.

everything correct or are there conceptual errors in what I wrote?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is one conceptual error I found in your understanding of working of the router.

The navigate method by default navigates to absolute path, starting from route (you can provide optional `relativeTo` option, though). The `routerLink` directive navigates to relative path (relatively to the component in which it is placed).

Other than that, your understandings about the router seem correct to me.

Comment: Thanks,  therefore when I use the navigate method and I don't insert the relativeTo option,  I always insert the complete absolute path as argument, in the navigate method array. Right?

Comment: In my example,however, both  1)this.router.navigate(['/home'])  and   2) <a [routerLink]="['/home']" take the absolute path as argument to navigate to home:  {path:'/home', component:HomeComponent}

Comment: You are absolutely right, the leading `/` makes sure that it is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

For me apart from **navigateByUrl('/home')** which you forget to enum, about the concept of navigation in angular all that you said is the same as i know...

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Would you please explain it to me?

Comment: i'm ok with you comprehension of routing in angular, in addition of the 3 methods for implement this in angular, you forget to list the "navigateByUrl()" method which don't take an array in argument but a simple name of a route for navigate on it